# Looping through values in different div's

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to loop through different divs. I've got product arrays, but they are displayed in different div's. Is there a way to loop through them? I would like to put the available products (array.length) in an Array. The code is as followed:

```html
<div id=Googletagsholderdiv data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.actionField.id="x"
  data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.actionField.affiliation="x" 
  data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue="x" 
  data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.actionField.tax="x" 
  data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.actionField.shipping="x"
  data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.actionField.coupon="x">
  <div data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[0].name="x" 
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[0].id="x" 
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[0].price="x" 
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[0].brand="x" 
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[0].category="x"
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[0].variant="x" 
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[0].quantity="x" 
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[0].coupon="x" 
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[0].dimensionX="x">
  </div>
  <div data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[1].name="x" 
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[1].id="x" 
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[1].price="x" 
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[1].brand="x" 
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[1].category="x"
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[1].variant="x" 
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[1].quantity="x" 
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[1].coupon="x" 
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[1].dimensionX="x">
  </div>
  <div data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[2].name="" 
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[2].id="x" 
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[2].price="x" 
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[2].brand="x" 
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[2].category=""
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[2].variant="x" 
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[2].quantity="x" 
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[2].coupon="x" 
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[2].dimensionX="x">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should had a class to all your div with your desired data, and after, get all of them with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the parent element with any selector you like and get it's children with the children array.

Yoi can loop through this array using the for..of loop:

```js
var Googletagsholderdiv = document.getElementById("Googletagsholderdiv");
for (var div of Googletagsholderdiv.children) {
  console.log(div);
}
```

```html
<div id=Googletagsholderdiv data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.actionField.id="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.actionField.affiliation="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.actionField.tax="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.actionField.shipping="x"
  data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.actionField.coupon="x">
  <div data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[0].name="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[0].id="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[0].price="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[0].brand="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[0].category="x"
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[0].variant="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[0].quantity="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[0].coupon="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[0].dimensionX="x"></div>
  <div data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[1].name="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[1].id="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[1].price="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[1].brand="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[1].category="x"
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[1].variant="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[1].quantity="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[1].coupon="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[1].dimensionX="x"></div>
  <div data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[2].name="" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[2].id="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[2].price="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[2].brand="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[2].category=""
    data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[2].variant="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[2].quantity="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[2].coupon="x" data-gtm-ecommerce.purchase.products[2].dimensionX="x"></div>
```